# how can page reload disabled when data get using ajax success function in javascript codeigniter php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a registration form and want to check if registered user will try to register again to show a alert window **already registered** using ajax function.

i have used codeigniter framework.

my function is working properly but when alert popup and press ok page is reloaded. i want to disable

my form code:

```
<form class="modal-content" name="form2" action="<?= $this->config->base_url();?>home/register_user" method="post" onSubmit="return ValidateRegister()">
                                              <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                          </button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Create your account</h4>
                        </div>
                       <div class="page-content vertical-align-middle" style="display:block;">
      <div class="form-group has-error">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputTokenfieldError-tokenfield"> <?php echo validation_errors();  ?></label>

                  </div>
        <div class="form-group form-material floating">
          <input type="text" class="form-control " id="inputName" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" autocomplete="off">
          <label class="floating-label">Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-material floating">
          <input type="email" class="form-control " id="my_email" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="floating-label">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-material floating">
          <input type="password" class="form-control " id="inputPassword" name="password" autocomplete="off">
          <label class="floating-label">Password</label>
        </div>

 <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Join Now - It's Free</button>
 </div>

      </form>
```

my javascript function:

```
function checkRegistrations() 
        {
            var email = $('#my_email').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?= base_url() ?>home/checkRegistration",
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                data: "email="+email,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data) {
                  //  alert(data);
                    if(data==1)
                    {

                    //event.preventDefault();
                    alert('Email already registered');
                    return false;
                    window.location.reload(false);
                    }
                    else{

                        return true;
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _want to disable my form code_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning true/false from inside an annon. function i.e. success handler. But parent function is not returning true/false.

Modify your code like this :

```
function checkRegistrations() 
        {
            var email = $('#my_email').val();
            var isValid = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?= base_url() ?>home/checkRegistration",
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                data: "email="+email,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data==1)
                    {
                    alert('Email already registered');
                    isValid = false;
                    }
                }
            });
           return isValid;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add an id to the submit button, say `#submitbutton`.

and use the `.prop()` method of `jQuery` to set the disabled attribute of the button.

```
$("#submitbutton").prop("disabled", true);
```

**IMP:** This will only work if you are keeping the same page on ajax `success`, But if you are **reloading** the page then you need to check it on `php` side whether this form has been submitted in this current `$_SESSION`.

So inside your `php` ajax handler, you can do the check as follows.

```
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST) && empty($_SESSION['post'])) {
    $_SESSION['post'] = true;
    ... do your code
    unset($_SESSION['post']);
}else{
// send the json encoded error message 
}
```

And on the `html` form just add a `hidden` `input` with the name `post` and set `value` to `1` or something whatever you deem fit, so once the form is submitted, the `post` key will be set inside the `$_SESSION` SuperGlobal Array, and if the same form is submitted twice by the **same** user then php wont accept it.